# Collect Email With My Application And Post On User Wall At The Same Time With An Auth Dialog

Tags: facebook, list, email, aweber

Please how can I collect email or build my email with aweber by using my application which can also post on user wall after the accept share it?  Like when I used your login button here, I had to allow access but I want more ( by posting on wall and collecting email using aweber)

How can I do it, specially building email list?

Comment: Are you trying to make an application to spam ?  o_O

Answer (score 1):

If you're limited to using awebber, I'd suggest contacting them directly: https://www.aweber.com/contact-us.htm

However, if you're open to other ways, you certainly can create an Facebook application using their public APIs.  See http://developers.facebook.com/  You can post to your app users walls.  You can also ask them for their email via that app too.  But there are limitations on how you can use that email. You should read thru http://developers.facebook.com/policy/